# Custom permission between two apps with different signatures

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have two application which are signed with different certs/keys.

I want to make **authenticated** call (to a service) from application A to app B (so no 3rd party can make such call).

Common solution for such things in Android is custom permissions with signature protection level. However, it won't work in my case, because two apps are signed with different certs (developed by different companies)

So, the question is. What is the best practice for this case, if I want allow only application A (or any apps developed by this company) to call/bind a service in app B?

Comment: This looks a lot like the web-service API client authentication problem, so perhaps you can find inspiration from solutions used there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't one, IMHO.

If the permission is not `signature`-based, the user can grant it to any app that asks for it, so a permission will not help you.

If you use services with the binding pattern, your `Binder` has `getCallingUid()`, which you can use to find the UID of the calling app. With some work, you can find out the package name for that UID from `PackageManager`. How you validate that package name is up to you (baked-in whitelist, try to make sense of the package's signature from `PackageManager`, whatever). That doesn't prevent somebody from messing with your APK and hacking your validation routine, though.

Comment: What about a validation of signature of your package? I mean, if you get Uid, get package, get signature and validate it against a certificate stored in application B? In this way, I think nobody can mess with application A APK, because the signature will be checked.

Comment: When you said "hacking your validation routine", did you mean changing application B (not A)?

Comment: @VictorRonin: Sorry, my answer was referring pretty much entirely to Application B, as it is the one that has to defend itself from attacks.

Comment: That idea would not work! Package name means nothing, as anyone is free to create an application in any package name they want, so long as such is not already installed *on that device*.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Agreed that anyone can try to write an Application A, though there's some chance checking Application A's signature might still be of use. If you have a better solution, though, post it as another answer.

Comment: Checking application A's signature is only useful if you have some other knowledge of application A's legitimate signature.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I interpreted "or any apps developed by this company" to mean that the OP has up-front info about Application A's authors.

Comment: @CommonsWare & ChrisStratton: Yes, both company A and B collaborate, so adding certificate for signature check isn't a problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I would appreciate, if you can look at continuation of my original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16724389/what-exactly-is-signature-class-in-android-and-how-to-get-signing-certificate